# Bones rotate instead of moving

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have a human rig with an IK on the leg. When I try to move the knee separately in pose mode the leg doesn't move. The knee has the cursor as if it was going to rotate and the text at the bottom says "Rot:" and then a number, but it rotates only slightly, as in I can barely see the pixels changing on my low-res screen. I have tried toggling Auto IK but it does nothing. It's just the bones, I haven't parented them to any mesh.[image: My bone setup without the human mesh]

Also my edit mode and object mode models of the bones are different, as the foot ans the IK bone are rotated in object but not in edit, and in pose mode the alt+g, alt+r and alt+s only make tiny adjustments as opposed to resetting the bone model as they are supposed to.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm just a noob! Thanks. (° ͜ʖ ͡ -)

Link: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D3aLuqHj1nXxXMG8Z3yd2RAwVcsBC0ZJ)

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make you leg work properly you need to:

- Deactivate the *Manipulate Center Points* option in *Pose* or *Object* mode (made to shift objects from each others) otherwise you won't be able to rotate anything.
- In *Edit* mode, give a correct parentage to your bones: Deparent the IK controller from any bone except the root bone that you will create at the end. Parent the foot bone to this controller.

[image]